# matcher.namedGroups(): Cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I have a pattern with named groups.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

String regexp = "(?<test>[a-z0-9]+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foobar");
Map<String, Integer> groups = matcher.namedGroups();
```

But when I try to get the groups with matcher.namedGroups(), I get the following error.

```bash
java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method namedGroups()
    location: variable matcher of type java.util.regex.Matcher
```

If I remove the line with matcher.namedGroups() and check in Intellij with Evaluate, the function is available.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: It looks like this method was [added in Java 20](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#namedGroups()). Is your project configured to use Java 20?